# Trying to create a global value, it gave me an error in php wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to make `$emo_word` a global variable so I can call it in another function. But whenever I put `global $emo_word`, it gives me the error below. If I remove `global`, it is OK, but I want to call the global, what can I do?

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'cat_id' in /home2/898992on708/public_html/mysitel.com/wp-content/plugins/gallery/gallery.php on line 212

```html
<?php

function name_1(){
  global $emo_word;
  $emo_word = array(
        1 => array(
      'word' => 'LOL !',
     'id_name' => 'lol',
     'cat_id' => '1'
     ),
        2 => array(
      'word' => 'COOL !',
     'id_name' => 'cool',
     'cat_id' => '2'
     )
          );
  foreach($emo_word as $word){
     $word['cat_id'];
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you using the `global` keyword inside of a function or outside of it?  (Is that your entire file in the snippet above?)

Comment: You're missing `$` before `word` (should be `$word['cat_id']`).

Comment: I am using global inside of the function. However, I also tried to use global outside the function, it gave me the same error.

Comment: the function above is fine, no errors, so its going to be where you are calling it. Where is the function used? do other functions access the global to change?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid but the error is telling you that there is a value in `$emo_word` that isn't an array but is instead a string.

If you were to run `var_dump($emo_word);` where you get that error you will see.

Essentially when you are accessing the `cat_id` index something like this is happening:

```
$emo_word = array(
    1 => array('cat_id' => 1, 'word' => 'LOL'),
    2 => 'string',
);
```

In the loop when it evaluates `$word['cat_id']` on the string value it throws the warning `Illegal string offset`.

Check your array to make sure it is contains what you expect.